# Objectvie C to swift migration for executefetchrequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How can i convert my OBJECTIVE-C code to swift. i tried so may time but executefetchrequest always returns NSArray at swift. i cannot parse to my Entity.

here is my objective C code and there is no error at obj-c.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"act_code==%@", @"0000"];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TblAct" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
TblAct *tblact_ = Nil;
NSError *err;
tblact_ = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&err] lastObject];
```

The below one is my swift. i got error at following code.

```
var request = NSFetchRequest()
request.shouldRefreshRefetchedObjects = false
var NSDesc:NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TblAct", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)
let act_codePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "act_code=%@", "0000")
request.entity = NSDesc
request.predicate = act_codePredicate
var err:NSError?
var result:TblAct? = contxt?.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &err) as? TblAct
```

THanks for any contribution.

Best Rgds,
dartfrog

Answer (score 1):

The `executeFetchRequest` method returns an optional array, but you're trying to accept it as a single entity. (Also, is `contxt` an optional? You're referencing it one place without `?` and one place with...)

```
var results: [TblAct]? = contxt.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &err) as? [TblAct]
var tableAccount: TblAct? = results?.last
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for answer. I got error in first line. "Consecutive statements on a line must be seperated by ';'". i thought because of [TblAct]. did i miss some namespace or declaration?